# Are "ultra-regular" bipartite graphs complete?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, regular-graph

Let $X, Y$ be non-empty, disjoint sets and let $R\subseteq X\times Y$ be a binary relation. For $x\in X$, we set $R(x) = \{y\in Y: (x,y) \in R\}$ and for $y\in Y$, let $R^{-1}(y) = \{x\in X:(x,y)\in R\}$. Moreover, for $A\subseteq X$, let $R(A) = \bigcup\{R(x):x\in A\}$.

We call $R$ *ultra-regular* if for every cardinal $\kappa>0$ we have

> Whenever $A, B\subseteq X$ and $|A| = |B| = \kappa$, then $|R(A)| = |R(B)|$.

Suppose that we have $R(x) > 1$ for every $x\in X$, and $R(y) > 1$ for every $y\in Y$, and assume that $R$ is regular. Does this imply that $R = X\times Y$?

Comment: There is a typo. It should be $R^{-1}(y)>0$ in the second last line.

Comment: And ".. assume that $R$  is regular" should be ".. assume that $R$  is ultra-regular". Otherwise $R=X\times X\setminus \Delta X$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: Wait it still is a counterexample for ultra-regular. Maybe I should post it as an answer...

Comment: for example if $R$ is a matching

Comment: @SeanEberhard Ok if $R$ is the complement of a matching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The complement of a matching generalises. Take $1<k<|X|$ and identify $Y$ with the $k$-subsets of $X$. Let $R(x)$ be the $k$-subsets containing $x$.

Note that the automorphism group acts as the symmetric group on $X$.  It would be nice to have examples without that property, but I think there aren't any. The sets $R(x)$ form a $t$-design for any $t$, which only allows complete designs and their unions as far as I know.

Comment: I was just about to comment the same thing. Note that $k=1$ gives the matching example. One can also take $Y$ to be the disjoint union of any number of levels $[n]^{(k)}$ (including copies of the same level), so this includes the complete bipartite case too. This might be all examples?

Comment: Why do you say the sets $R(x)$ form a $t$-design? E.g., if $Y = X \times [2]$ with $x \in X$ joined to $(x,1)$ and $(x,2)$ for all $x$, then the $R(x)$'s are not a $2$-design.

Comment: I guess you mean the sets $R^{-1}(y)$ form a $t$-design for any $t$, which does seem to follow from inclusion--exclusion. So yes I agree it seems there are no other examples.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Right, I had it in reverse, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: For the claim on automorphisms, one may relax the condition as follows. Assume that we have a permutation $\sigma\in S(X)$ such that $|R(A)|=|R(\sigma(A)|$ for all $A\subset X$. Then there exists an automorphism of the whole graph whose restriction to $X$ is $\sigma$. The proof is the same inclusion-exclusion manipulation.,